# Get the Number of Frames in a Dynamically Loaded Flash File

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

It has been a really long time since I used flash and I am creating a small presentation in which I recorded some videos of my screen and have them exported as .swf files. I am currently able to dynamically load them into a parent flash file using

```
this.video_mc.loadMovie(movieString);
```

The problem is I have 6 different videos that get loaded when different buttons are pressed. I would like to change it so that when 1 video finishes the next one will play and eventually loop back.

My question is how can I get the number of frames within these loaded .swf videos (_currentframe) so that I can know when it finishes so that I may start the next file or is there an easier way to do this?

*I am using AS2 btw.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the SWFs are loaded you can look at their _totalframes property.

Comment: Once the first frame is loaded, in fact.